# Получение списка подъездов у дома

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Получаю список домов в заданном полигоне, и задался вопросом: "как получить подъезды у дома?".
Пробовал логировать объект дома и смотреть свойства - там ничего связаного с entrances нету.
В API Yandex Maps про entrances упоминаний вообще нет.

Возможно, я что-то упускаю?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, например, получить координаты подъезда через Геокодер:
[https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=7d414129-bdb5-4dbf-9f93-0d0aa59d2fba&geocode=Россия,%20Москва,Мичуринский%20проспект,%2017,%20подъезд%202&kind=locality](https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=7d414129-bdb5-4dbf-9f93-0d0aa59d2fba&geocode=%D0%A0%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F,%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%87%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82,%2017,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B4%202&kind=locality)